# Use highlighted file in Finder as Bash variable (Applescript, macOS 10.13)

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, automator, finder

I want to set up an applet for archiving my files in non-standard formats (e.g. non .zip/.cpgz/.tar) with only the use of Applescript and the command line versions of each format's respective tool. The last thing I need to figure out is how to get the path of the currently highlighted file in Finder via Applescript, so that I can pipe it to bash.

I've searched around a bit and can't seem to find an answer to this via search engine, or this forum. I have found and still find that Apple's documentation has about a 40/60 chance of being too sparse and/or outdated, or even simply nonexistent for any given subject, so I opt not to use it when possible. Please don't just link to an Apple documentation page, Real-world examples are always appreciated.

The target platform is macOS 10.13.2, Automator 2.8, Applescript 2.7.

Comment: Note that had you provided more information in your OP, I could have targeted my answer to actual conditions, not just shown one way how to get the POSIX path filename needed for use in a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more then one way to do it and also depends on how may **Finder** *items* are selected. Here's an example if only one *item* is selected in **Finder**:

```
set theTarget to POSIX path of (application "Finder"'s selection as string)
```

Or, if the pathname has spaces, use:

```
set theTarget to quoted form of POSIX path of (application "Finder"'s selection as string)
```

Sans the shown examples, the other ways can depend on how/where it falls in the rest of your *code* and whether or not more then one *item* is selected in Finder, however this is a place to start.

---

BTW If you're doing this **AppleScript** from `bash`, not **Script Editor** where the other examples were *run*, then using `osascript` in `bash` to run the same *example* **AppleScript**  *code* shown above, with a single *item* selected in **Finder**, it would be:

```
theTarget="$(osascript -e "POSIX path of (application \"Finder\"'s selection as string)")"
```

Or:

```
theTarget="$(osascript -e "quoted form of POSIX path of (application \"Finder\"'s selection as string)")"
```